# What hash algorithm does postgres 10 use for varchars?

Tags: postgresql

If I apply a hash index on a varchar, what algorithm will postgres 10 use to hash the value? Will it be MD5? Murmur3? FNV-1? I am unable to find this documented anywhere.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the particular algorithm matter to you?

Comment: Oh, the joy of open source, and people not being able to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the correct function with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.amproc
FROM pg_amproc p
   JOIN pg_opfamily f ON p.amprocfamily = f.oid
   JOIN pg_am a ON f.opfmethod = a.oid
WHERE a.amname = 'hash'
  AND p.amproclefttype = 'text'::regtype;
```

The function is `hashtext`, and it calls `hash_any` from `backend/access/hash/hashfunc.c` internally.

The comments for this function tell you more:

```
/*
 * This hash function was written by Bob Jenkins
 * (bob_jenkins@burtleburtle.net), and superficially adapted
 * for PostgreSQL by Neil Conway. For more information on this
 * hash function, see http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html,
 * or Bob's article in Dr. Dobb's Journal, Sept. 1997.
 *
 * In the current code, we have adopted Bob's 2006 update of his hash
 * function to fetch the data a word at a time when it is suitably aligned.
 * This makes for a useful speedup, at the cost of having to maintain
 * four code paths (aligned vs unaligned, and little-endian vs big-endian).
 * It also uses two separate mixing functions mix() and final(), instead
 * of a slower multi-purpose function.
 */
```